# Setup an ssh account that can only be used for a socks5 proxy

Tags: ssh, proxy, socks

I have an arch linux machine behind a firewall.
I can open a port forwarding for the ssh port.
I would like to create a user that can be used only for a socks proxy.

```
ssh -N -D 5000 user@server -p9000
```

`5000` will be the local port the user uses for socks5 proxy

`server:9000` is the ssh port of the server (the port forwarding)

`-N` means that a terminal shouldn't be opened. I will create the user with a default shell being `/sbin/nologin`.

Now the problem is that the user can forward local ports (`-L8080:server2:80`) and I want to avoid this.

Also I want the proxy to not proxy connections to anything in the server's internal network.

Is that achievable easily or not?

Are there other pitfalls I have to think about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Jakuje](https://serverfault.com/users/186199/jakuje) mentioned, you can use options to forbid forwarding.

**Restricting Outbound Traffic by Owner**

> Also I want the proxy to not proxy connections to anything in the server's internal network.

You can you the iptables `owner` module to allow specific groups and users outbound in the `OUTPUT` rules to specific locations such as your ssh gateway server, but then block everything else.  The owner module can match on gid or uid.  This method is also commonly used in conjunction with Tor.

You can also use this to allow specific daemons to reach specific services.  e.g. If using ldap, you can allow the ldap service account to query your ldap server and nothing else.

If using iptables in this manor, you may first want to allow (but log) traffic so that you know what would have been dropped.

Comment: No problem. Good teamwork! :)

Comment: And whose answer should be the correct one?

Comment: Entirely up to you.  Perhaps whichever of ours moved you closer to your goal.  Or flip a coin.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can forbid local forwarding in `sshd_config`, for example:

```
Match User your_user
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  PermitOpen none
```

It should not affect Dynamic forwarding/SOCKS proxy.

> Also I want the proxy to not proxy connections to anything in the server's internal network.

This needs to be set up somewhere else then in `ssh`.

Comment: When I add either of these lines, the `-D` proxy doesn't work anymore. But it seems to be a bit finicky (working 2 out of 3 times) anyhow on Windows (maybe some close_wait states idk) so take this with a grain of salt. However, what you can add is `Match User your_user \n PermitTTY no` as well as having the `/usr/sbin/nologin` shell set for the user.